# How to retrieve delicious related tags

Tags: similarity, delicious-api, related-content

I have found this example [here](http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001049.html) which uses delicious related tags and create a graph. But I don't know how they implemented it. I don't know how to get a list of related tags from delicious API, because in the documentation it is not mentioned at all, but in delicious [website](http://delicious.com/) when you search for a tag it shows related tags in the right hand.

Does anybody know how to get related tags using API?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer to [Delicious' API page](https://www.delicious.com/help/api).  There is [specific section on getting tags](https://www.delicious.com/help/api#tags_get).

Not knowing what language you're using (I didn't see any examples in the link you provided; admittedly I didn't dig too deep), I'm presenting some Python which uses the [urllib.FancyURLopener](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.FancyURLopener):

```
import urllib
u = urllib.FancyURLopener({})
f = u.open("https://api.del.icio.us/v1/tags/get")
tags = f.readlines()
for tag_line in tags:
    print tag_line
```

Notes about this code:

1. The [urllib doc page](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) contains this caveat about using the module with https:

> Warning - When opening HTTPS URLs, it does not attempt to validate the server certificate. Use at your own risk!
>
> As coded above, you will be prompted for your Delicious username & password.  To work around this, you need to override the [prompt_user_password](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.FancyURLopener.prompt_user_passwd) method.
>
> As you may have guessed by the need for authentication, this only gets tags for the user whose credentials you provide.  I did not see how to get tags for all of Delicious.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the problem. I need to retrieve RELATED TAGS not just tags. Did you understand what I mean?

Comment: For instance, if you search http://delicious.com/search?p=java, as a related tags it offers (java, toread, programación, java.net, español, accessibility, wsman, programacion) tags. Eventhough I don't know how these tags are related but I need to get these related tags from there.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor:  [This question at Delicious](http://support.delicious.com/delicious/topics/where_are_related_tags) seems to imply that related tags has not yet been implemented in the re-design that Delicious went through when AVOS bought it from Yahoo, at least as far as something you can get directly via the API.  That seems to leave screen scraping, for which there are already SO questions and other Google-able sites.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor:  Looking at this a bit more I see that the Related Tags div isn't always populated in the page source, but still shows items listed.  I suspect they're doing this with Javascript, but haven't the time (or expertise, really) to figure out more.