# How To Access Delicious API to Retrieve Google Related Keywords

Tags: python, delicious-api

I am looking for a way to retrieve relevant keywords for a search term, and was thinking about using the the delicious API for this goal:

I found some websites which used the delicious API for this purpose that are also mentioned in my quoted stackoverflow question:

[How to retrieve delicious related tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069739/how-to-retrieve-delicious-related-tags)
For example: http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001049.html

I went through the delicious API  but did not find any function that could give me the result that I wanted.

Does delicious.com still offer this functionality? And if so how could I use it with Python?

I was trying to retrieve some data with this Python wrapper class:
https://github.com/mudge/python-delicious but it also seems to have lack of functionality to retrieve related keywords.

Comment: Have you tried NLTK to retrieve relevant search terms for a keyword e.g. through wordnet?

Comment: Yes NLTK is already a keyword source I am trying to to find further sources for my keyword analysis.

Comment: Of course there are other NLP projects. A good overview you can find here: http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/projects.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to find related keywords using Python:

```
import requests
import xmltodict
import json
import re

KEYWORD = 'best icecream'

res     = requests.get('https://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&gl=eg&q={}'.format({re.sub("\s", "_", KEYWORD)}))
obj     = xmltodict.parse(res.text)
json    = json.dumps(obj)

print(json)
```

Result preview:

```json
{
   "toplevel":{
      "CompleteSuggestion":[
         {
            "suggestion":{
               "@data":"best ice cream scoop"
            }
         },
         {
            "suggestion":{
               "@data":"best ice cream places"
            }
         },
         {
            "suggestion":{
               "@data":"best ice cream places near me"
            }
         },
         {
            "suggestion":{
               "@data":"best ice cream in india"
            }
         },
         {
            "suggestion":{
               "@data":"best ice cream in rome"
            }
         },
         {
            "suggestion":{
               "@data":"best keto ice cream"
            }
         },
         {
            "suggestion":{
               "@data":"best vanilla ice cream"
            }
         },
         {
            "suggestion":{
               "@data":"best ice cream"
            }
         },
         {
            "suggestion":{
               "@data":"best ice cream maker"
            }
         },
         {
            "suggestion":{
               "@data":"best ice cream brands"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```